# CPU wait state (RAM) stats?

Tags: memory, top, load-average, iowait

As far as I understand, the `wa` % stat displayed by `top` is the I/O wait (i.e. hard drive).

Is there a way to get similar wait stats, but for when the CPU is [waiting for memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait_state)?

My server is pretty much always `0.0 wa`, because I've got an NVMe SSD, and a large RAM. But I would be interested in finding out **how much CPU time is spent on waiting for the RAM** (and measure the impact of RAM speed on my workload).

Is there any way to find this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a precise number, you need to tap into CPU's performance counter. You can use `oprofile` and/or `perf` to get an inside view of how your CPU/memory/application combo performs.

Comment: Thanks, so this is not available system-wise, I guess because of the overhead it would add?

Comment: It **is** available system-wide, via an appropriate profiling utility as the two suggested above. However, as these performance counters are CPU and platform specific, no "standard" Unix tool exists to accurately measure them (note: `top` and other standard utilities can give approximate and useful results via **minor page faults** count)